# High Performance Development

Tags: c#, performance, design-patterns

**Background**

We have been working very hard to try come up with solutions for a "High Performance" application. The application is basically a high throughput in-memory manager, with a sync back to disk. The "reads" and "writes" are tremendously high, around 3000 transactions a second. We try and do as much as possible in memory, but eventually the data gets stale and needs to be flushed to disk, and this is where a huge "bottleneck" ensues. The app is multi-threaded, with about 50 threads. There is no IPC (inter-process comms)

**Attempts**

We initially wrote this in Java, and it worked quite well, up until a certain load, the bottleneck was hit and it just couldn't keep up.
Then we tried it in C#, and the same bottle-neck was reached.
We tried this with unmanaged code (C#), and though on initial tests was blindingly fast using MMF (Memory-map files), in production, reading was slow (are using Views).
We did try CouchBase, but we stumbled into problems surround high network utilization. This might be poor configuration on our part!

**Extra Info:** In our Java attempt (non-MMF), our thread with the Queue of information that needs to get flushed to disk builds to the extent of being unable to keep up "writing" to disk.
In our C# Memory-Map File Approach, the problems is that READS are very slow, and the WRITES working perfectly. For some reason, the Views are slow!

**Question**

So the question is, situations where you intend of transferring massive amounts of data; can someone please assist with a possible approach or architectural design that might be able to assist? I know this seems a bit broad, but I think the specific nature of high performance, high throughput should narrow down the answers.

Can anyone vouch for using Couchbase, MongoDB or Cassandra at such a level? Other ideas or
solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think writing data in other thread to disk when when certain limit reached (but not huge number, for example a quarter of what you are using now) while keep reading data can help. Then you can free this memory and begin writing others. I don't really know the answer I just think that it can help

Comment: Not sure if it fits to your data transferring issue but there was a software design shown in a paper of the University of California. "SEDA: An Architecture for Well-Conditioned, Scalable Internet Services". ACM ISBN 1-58113-389-8-1/01/10. It talks about how to obtain high throughput in a multithreaded/-staged system.

Comment: Adil, thanks we are doing that. Coding.mof will check out the paper, much appreciated.

Comment: How are you sharding the data among disks? 

Also, I can't personally vouch for how Mongo performs under such high loads, but they seem to place a lot of emphasis on speed and provide a lot of facilities for trying to distribute read/write load among several servers/disks.

Comment: You say you've tried Java/C#/Unmanaged C# and everything was slow. Sounds like the architecture and dev environment are not the issue here, rather you are simply trying to just do too much on your current hardware. You need some serious power here, and I would advise spending some money on some serious hardware.

Comment: We were using Couchbase to do that previously. At the moment and by initial design, it was a single box, which had multiple threads; one of them had a queue of data that needed to get flushed to disk. At the moment we are trying memory mapped files (C#), and there is no problem of "writes" as it's managed by OS, but a problem of READ. Just can't win :)

Comment: How often do your read? Can't you use a FIFO queue which a thread is constantly reading to to make sure that X objects always are available for the processing thread?

Comment: I'm confused by the high network utilization. I'm not familiar with Couchbase, but in Mongo, the client would connect to a (possibly local) mongos process, the mongos process would then connect to the correct shard and retrieve the results. For querying a single object on a primary index you'd just hit one server, you might have some overhead for requests and serialization and occasional config updates, but I don't see how that would suddenly make the network unusable...

Comment: Keith take a look at this, https://raw.github.com/dspezia/redis-doc/client_command/topics/Data_size.png. This performance for us, is unacceptable and this is REDIS. To fulfil our requirement we would need 5000 machines. I guess there is no easy solution or hack; the tunnel is narrowing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Massive amounts of data and disk access. What kind of disk are we talking about? HDDs tend to spend a lot of time moving the head around if you work with more than one file. (That shouldn't be a problem if you use SSDs, though.) Also, you should take advantage of the fact that memory-mapped files are managed in page-sized chunks. Data structures should be aligned to page boundaries, if possible.

But in any case, you must make sure you know *what* the bottleneck is. Optimizing data structures wouldn't help much if you actually lose the time due to thread synchronization, for example. And if you're using a HDD, page alignment might not help as much as stuffing everything into a single file somehow. So use appropriate tools to figure out which brakes are still holding you back.

Using a general-purpose database implementation might not help you as much as you hope. They are, after all, general-purpose. If performance really is that much of an issue, a special implementation with your requirements in mind might outperform these more general implementations.

Comment: Such a profiling tool e.g. for Java is [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html?gclid=CKOD54mM7rECFRHMzAod2QkAMw)

Comment: Hi Wormbo, thanks. Good tips; I researched the SSD route previously, but unfortunately because of the "cell" problems of limit reads and writes despite updated algorithms to prevent this by hardware manufacturers; our processing rate will kill the disk in a short period. Can you elaborate on "Data structure aligning to page boundaries"? why is that beneficial?

Comment: coding.mof, yip done the profiling thing, using IBM products as well as Microsofts. Thanks

Comment: @DaneBalia: You might like to share what you discovered with your profiling.

Comment: Wormbo hit the nail on the head when he said "make sure you know what the bottleneck is". The bottleneck according to our profiling revealed problems first with "jvm not releasing memory". Upon further expectation we noticed it was Queues not releasing objects, which points straight back at the disk being unable to keep up (I/O).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and comments. Going to try Redis, as it appears to be best for our needs, if that doesn't work, will will write our own implementation. Link below might help others: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/

Comment: If it's really the I/O part, then you might need deep understanding on how the file system and memory-mapped files work to be able to improve anything. Since SSDs are no option for you, it is even more important to get all related data grouped closely together on the physical disk. That should help the disk's own cache and Windows' file cache predict required data. Also, what I meant by "page-aligning" the data is that memory-mapped files are read in fixed-size chunks with fixed boundaries. With a page size of 4k, reading 2k of data starting at 3k, you will need two pages instead of one.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would like to make clear that I have little (if any) experience building high-performance, scalable applications..

Martin Fowler has a description of the LMAX architecture that allowed an application to process about 6 million orders per second on a single thread. I'm not sure it can help you (as you seemingly need to move alot of data), but maybe you can get some ideas from it: http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

The architecture is based on [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) which is often used to provide (relatively) easy scalability.

Comment: That looks promising, takes a bit of time to kind of get the "concept". But will see if we can get something out from the Disruptor pattern.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't really solve our problem. Disruptor pattern focuses more on when there is alot of work (steps of work) to be done, and that contention between work (for example, that found in Queue). Our problem is in a Queue that is stand-alone and unable to write efficiently to disk, without the Queue reaching an unmanageable size.

Answer (score -1):

If you want fast avoid persistence and queues as much as possible for writes and use memory sores/ caching on reads.

Language has little to do with it.\

Comment: Not sure on the down vote .. languages generally vary by about 10-30% ( some by 50% ). But IO to disk is like 10K slower than memory.. Look at Lmax minimize IO and do 6M transactions / second on a single machine . Same goes for common usage use a persistent queue and i guarantee your throughput will reduce by at least a factor of 10.  And you have the horrible manual maintenance of dead letter queues.    Now look at the language figures compared to persistent costs..  That does not mean you dont have persistent but minimizing it helps..